# python: cv2.threshold changes numpy to tuple

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, motion-detection

I process every frame in first function where i am using`cv2.threshold(self.res, 10, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)` for preprocessing before detecting motion. In next function I am just counting number of black pixels and calculating average. I am giving a numpy array to `cv2.threshold` but it returns me `tuple` and when i try to count black pixels here `if self.res[x,y] == 0.0:` i get this type error `tuple indices must be integers, not tuple` . It's been two days but no luck.

```
def processImage(self, frame):

        self.frame2gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        self.res = cv2.absdiff(self.frame1gray, self.frame2gray)
        self.res = cv2.GaussianBlur(self.res, (15, 15), 0)
        kernel = np.ones((3, 3), np.uint8)
        self.res = cv2.morphologyEx(self.res, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)
        self.res = cv2.morphologyEx(self.res, cv2.MORPH_GRADIENT, kernel)
        self.res = cv2.threshold(self.res, 10, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)

        print "type: ",type(self.res)

def somethingHasMoved(self):

        nb=0 #Will hold the number of black pixels
        for x in range(self.height): #Iterate the hole image
            for y in range(self.width):

                if self.res[x,y] == 0.0:
                    nb += 1
        avg = (nb*100.0)/self.nb_pixels #Calculate the average of black pixel in the image
    print"average movement : ",avg
        if avg > self.threshold:#If over the ceiling trigger the alarm
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

Comment: `cv2.threshold` returns two outputs, that's why you are getting a tuple of two elements. You need the second one, so do : `cv2.threshold(res, 10, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)[1]`.